# Fluent Nhibernate QueryOver fetch record only by Date without time

Tags: c#, linq, orm, fluent-nhibernate

**I have following object:**

```
 public class DomainMenu:EntityBase
    {
        public virtual DomainName DomainName { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime PlannedDate { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public virtual string Notes { get; set; }                  

    }
```

**And mapping:**

```
    public class DomainMenuMap : ClassMap<DomainMenu>
    {
        public DomainMenuMap()
        {
            Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(c => c.PlannedDate);
            Map(c => c.CreationDate);
            Map(c => c.Notes);
            References(c => c.DomainName);

        }
    }
```

**I have following method :**

```
    public IList<DomainMenu> GetDomainMenuesPlannedForNextDays(int domainId)
    {
        using (_unitOfWorkFactory.Create())
        {
            var todayDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

            var list = _domainMenuRepository.QueryOver()
                .Where(c=>c.PlannedDate.Date >= todayDate)
                .Where(c => c.DomainName.Id == domainId)
                .Future().ToList();
            return list;
        }
    }
```

In this method I want to get rows that have PlannedDate bigger or equal with today date.I want to compare only date value, without time, but I am getting following error:

> could not resolve property: PlannedDate.Date of: DomainMenu

Is it possible to it using QueryOver in Fluent Nhibernate or not?
Note: I am interested only in using this solution , I do not want different methods as I already know them, I just want to know if it's possible with QueryOver.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

NHibernate doesn't know what to do with the Date property, it's .Net property and the QueryOver API can't handle it.

Have a look at this blog on how to extend queryover with custom methods and properties

http://blog.andrewawhitaker.com/blog/2015/01/29/queryover-series-part-9-extending-queryover-using-custom-methods-and-properties/